# I want my <h1> to use a font I have downloaded

Tags: css, font-face

I am creating am email flyer and I was to be able to use a custom font for my headers (`<h1>`), not the whole page.

this is the code I am using but it doesn't seem to work when I view it in Outlook. Is this a CSS problem or does Outlook not deal with the code well?

I have the font file in the same location as my html file too.

```
@font-face {
font-family:Bebas;
src:url(BEBAS__.TTF);
}
```

Comment: If you use @font-face in HTML email, Outlook 07/10/13 will default all text back to Times New Roman: http://emailwizardry.nightjar.com.au/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is the font path. You have to give absolute path for your font to work on email clients.

**For Instance,**

`src:url(BEBAS__.TTF);` which should be converted to something like this `src:url(http://www.yourdomain.com/BEBAS__.TTF);`

Comment: what is an absolute path position?

Comment: absolute path is for instance, `www.google.com/images/logo.png` and not `../images/logo.png`

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure what you mean by `<link>` tag.

Comment: my font file is in the same location as the html file and it's all zipped up and then hosted online

Comment: But that does not work for email clients. You should convert all the paths to absolute paths.

Comment: I am talking about this `src:url(BEBAS__.TTF);` which should be converted to something like this `src:url(http://www.yourdomain.com/BEBAS__.TTF);` - @Adsy

Answer (score 0):

as suggest by Nathan you need to have absolute path 
e.g.

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'bebasregular';
src: url('BEBAS___-webfont.eot');
src: url('BEBAS___-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('BEBAS___-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('BEBAS___-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('BEBAS___-webfont.svg#bebasregular') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to give an absolute path position here is a simple example:

```
@font-face {
font-family:Bebas;
src:url("c:\\path\\to\\font\\BEBAS__.TTF");
}
```

That should work. If not try it without the "".

As you said It is hosted online. It should not be zipped as this wont work. If you have to link to where the file is (Once unzipped) put it like this:

```
@font-face {
font-family:Bebas;
src:url("www.yourwebsite.com/thepath/BEBAS__.TTF");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way for using web fonts in email :

http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3897/using-web-fonts-in-email

Answer (score 0):

Even thou you'll give the correct path for your font as Nathan suggested I'm pretty sure it still won't work.

The idea is **not to use CSS** at all when your are making an email layout in the **header** zone, like you do on a normal html page. The problem is that some e-mail clients will ignore your header.